# Pandas Lookup on matching field

Tags: pandas

df1 is table of products

```
product_name, product_cost, product_desc
```

df2 is lookup table

```
product_name
```

want to lookup if df1.product_name exists on df2 and if so set flag on df1 to 1 else 0

tried

```
df['isaprod'] = np.where(df1[df1.product_name.isin(df2.product_name)], 1, 0)
```

got

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

tried

```
df['isaprod'] = np.where(df1[df1.product_name.isin(df2.product_name)], 1, 0)
```

got

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: You are passing a `dataframe` into the first argument of `np.where` when it should be a `array_like, bool`.  It should be: `df['isaprod'] = np.where(df1.product_name.isin(df2.product_name), 1, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

why not

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='product_name', how='right')
df['isaprod'] = np.where(df['product_name'].isnull(),0,1)
```